# Same activities not working the same on android 6.0

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-runtime

I am making an RSS feed app using CardView and RecyclerView, but whenever one of the cards is clicked on, the app with crash and give an AndroidRuntimeException that i cannot figure out.

```
holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                if(!isLongClick) {
                    url = rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink();
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){

                        //String weblink = new String(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink());

                        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Browser.class);
                        //i.putExtra("URL", url);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        mContext.startActivity(i);

                    } else {
                        //Once I figure out the fix, gonna use this section for older versions
                        //Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
                       //mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
                        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Browser.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(i);
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

I also have a button in the toolbar that opens another activity but with a static url, and that page works just fine; the problem occurs whenever the page is called using the ".getLink()" url. The Browser class activity is as follows..

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser_layout);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Hillsdale Watch");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(FeedAdapter.url);


    }
```

Both pages work perfectly fine on Android 7.0 but not on anything below. Help!

Here is the crash report that shows in the google developer page.

```
LGE LG X Style (k6b), 1536MB RAM, Android 6.0

android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:672)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:659)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity (ContextWrapper.java:331)
  at com.hillsdalewatch.rssfeed.Adapter.FeedAdapter$1.onClick (FeedAdapter.java:143)
  at com.hillsdalewatch.rssfeed.Adapter.FeedViewHolder.onClick (FeedAdapter.java:52)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5217)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:21349)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5585)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: Have you tried getApplicationContext () instead of mContext. Just a guess haha i read your other post too

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: The first line says at android.app.ContextImpl.. just thought that has something to do with the context

Comment: Just tried it, but it says "Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()'".

Comment: Maybe getActivity ().getBaseContext () there are a bunch of ways to get context.

Comment: Did you try adding the newtask flag? Im looking around. In the else

Comment: I did not! I forgot to add it there! Here's to hoping it works!

Comment: That fixed the issue for 5.0 devices! I'm hoping it does the same for 6.0! I have none to test with and android studio emulator doesn't work for me, so I have to wait for user feedback